# Access query works fine in the morning, stops working later in the day

Tags: ms-access

I have this Access database that we use to run reports. The report is run twice a day every working day.

For some reason the report will run fine usually in the morning but every now and then it will stop working. I go to debug and it will show a different query failed to run every time.

So far there are two ways to fix this. Close the application and re-open, or refresh the linked tables. I would really like to know why this is happening and if possible how to prevent it.

The tables are connected through ODBC which points to SQL Server 2000. The error messages usually say "Could not connect to --". In between -- should be the ODBC connection name but it doesn't display.

There are about 10 linked tables. The computers are on wired LAN. If I open one of the failed queries and try to run it fails. When I refresh/reopen it works.

When I say go to debug I mean that when the error occurs it gives me two options end/debug. I click debug and it opens up the modules (VBA code) window.

Comment: ` I can provide more information if requested.` I think you should. :) I don't see how anybody can answer this with the information provided. Post some error messages from the queries that fail for example. One wild guess comes to mind: Memory usage, either on the disk or in the RAM.

Comment: The reason I didn't include the queries that are failing is because its a different one everytime. It seems its losing connection for some reason.

Comment: Well, is this report an Access report? A macro? A VBA procedure? What do you mean when you say "I go to debug"?

Comment: Can you track the errors? Maybe a pattern will show itself.

Comment: ODBC? Jet/ACE back end? SQL Server? MySQL? And as @Tmdean asked, VBA, macro, what? What are some of the error messages?

Comment: @Tmdean, ODBC connection to SQL Server, and VBA. The error messages are usually "Could not Connect to --" It doesn't even say the ODBC connection name.

Comment: Sounds like your queries are timing out. I think PowerUser might have the correct answer below.

Comment: You should check the DNS configuration on the workstations. I've seen intermittent ODBC connection problems because the workstation DNS was pointing to the Internet provider's DNS instead of the local domain's DNS, and the Internet provider had no entry for the SQL Server. Using the domain controller as the primary DNS removes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usually in the morning but every now and then it will stop working`

This sounds REAL familiar to me. Perhaps your company servers are so backed up at this time that your reports are giving time out errors? I recommend scheduling your reports at a different time. If your boss says No, tell him/her "Ok, It will continue to run in the morning, but it may not always go out."

Answer (score 1):

Could someone be changing the definitions of the tables that are linked?  If so, that might be the problem.